# How can I quantify muscle tightness?

Tags: muscle, measurement

How can I quantify muscle tightness? I'm mostly interested in forarm muscles.

I could ask a physical therapist to assess muscle tightness by touching the muscle. What are other solutions? The more objective and reproducible the measurement, the better.

---

Examples of use cases:

Use case 1: I want to study the impact of treatment X on muscle tightness. I would like to measure the muscle tightness before and after treatment X is applied.

Use case 2: I want to study the correlation between forarm muscles tightness and tendinopathy (epicondylopathy).

Comment: My first question was deleted, so now I have written it in a different way: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/316214/alternatives-for-emg-muscle-sensors

Comment: @Jot thanks for working on it! I am swamped under work this summer but definitely keeping a close eye on it.